# Archviz animation - skip every frame and use FlowFrames or temporal data denoising?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, denoise

I’ve been having trouble with the best method to render an interior archviz animation scene in Blender, using Cycles.
In my opinion, there are two methods:

1 - Render every other frame (resulting in 15fps, for example), and then interpolate with Flowframes, getting a result of 30fps Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mt3ppld1vAc&list=PLnxIfcSg1evy1YOQRmk4pBBqvHXGSjBNS&index=337&ab_channel=MediaWay

2 - Render every frame traditionally, and use temporal data denoising like the one that exists in Super Image Denoiser or with K-Cycles.

I can’t decide what’s the best method. The first one seems faster (because we’re cutting the rendered frames in half, and I’ve had great results), but I don’t know if it’s necessary to keep the number of samples high to compensate the lack of temporal data denoising…

The second method is the traditional one, and I think that by using temporal data denoising one can get good results with lower samples.

Using the first method I tried to use temporal data denoising with K-Cycles, but an error message appeared that said I didn’t have a sequence. It might have been because the numbering became 0001, 0003, 0005…I’m wondering if I change the sequence numbering to something like 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004… I can make the temporal data denoising work…

What’s your opinion with all of this?

P.S.: I know that each scene requires different values, but what’s a good rule of thumb? Maintaining the samples at 4096 and change the threshold or lower the samples and keep the threshold at 0.01 (for example)?